# How do I play custom audio for Toast notifications?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone

I can receive Toast notifications on my phone, but I can't seem to specify the audio it should play.

I've modified the toast XML to include a sound, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
  <wp:Toast>
    <wp:Text1>TOAST TEXT</wp:Text1>
    <wp:Text2>This is a toast</wp:Text2>
  </wp:Toast>
  <wp:Sound>myfile.mp3</wp:Sound>
</wp:Notification>
```

But this doesn't work.

What do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toast with sound works only on Windows Phone 8 Update 3 and later versions. Make sure the file you specified in your XML is stored in the proper location. Also make sure the sound file is less than 10 seconds long.

> Windows Phone 8 Update 3 (OS version number 8.0.10492) introduces the
>   ability to provide a custom sound for toast notifications. Sound files
>   can be in WAV, WMA, or MP3 format, must be less than 10 seconds long,
>   and **must be stored in the app’s installation directory or local
>   storage folder**.
>
> To use a custom sound for a toast that is launched via a cloud
>   service, all you need to do is include a Sound element in the XML
>   payload. To launch a silent toast, you can use the Silent attribute,
>   set to “true”.

See code samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Toastproperties).